# Import music into iPhone without deleting everything

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, music, import

My OSX crashed and I installed it completely new (no backup). Now I wanted to import some music into my iPhone and it seems it is not possible. Every time I get the warning that everything get deleted if I synchronize it with iTunes. If I want to manage the music/video manually I also get this message. What can I do? The data on my iPhone should stay. I only want to add something ...

PS: Does it mean that my backup made with iTunes will not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a backup before you do this. My solution was the following:

-Select the following option: Manually manage videos/Music
-Sync and delete
-Add music to the iPhone via iTunes

The sync refers to the music library. If you have music on your iPhone it will be deleted (except it is already synched with your iTunes library). Because I had no music on it that wasn't a problem. You have to be aware of that your ringtones will be deleted! The other data wasn't removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you never synced the iPhone with your PC/Mac, you cannot manually add songs without first deleting the iPhone (I am 99% sure about this).

You can use third party iTunes alternatives (i.e. [CopyTrans Manager](http://www.copytrans.net/copytransmanager.php) for PC and [Sharepod](http://www.getsharepod.com/download/mac/) for Mac to add songs to the iPhone without the need to sync with iTunes.

Comment: Are these apps: `Sharepod`, `CopyTrans Manager` unlimited, free?

Answer (score 1):

I use iTools program (exists for Mac and Windows) to copy my MP3 files to my iOS device without completely synchronizing my music library. No existing files will be deleted, just new files will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Music can't be synced in the direction of iphone to mac (this has been this way for iPods since day one to prevent piracy). 
There are several apps (like phoneview) that allow you to copy the music from an iPhone to your drive. 
Songs that were purchased via iTunes can simply be downloaded again using the same account.

Comment: I don't want to sync from iPhone to Mac. I have music files on my PC/Mac and I want to import them on my iPhone without deleting the data on my iPhone. The songs where not purchased in iTunes.

Comment: There's a checkmark "manage music manually". Check it and hit apply. Then use drag and drop to put music on your phone

Comment: I tried that already. If I hit apply I get the message again that it will be synched with my library and everything from the iPhone gets deleted ...